# passing arguments to unittest.TestSuite and using xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner

Tags: unit-testing, optionparser

I am writing some tests which use the python unittest package (Python 2.7) 
and I heavily rely on the xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner to dump the XML test output

Unfortunately, I fail to find some basic example which describes how one can  pass some command line options to the test class to parametrise some of the tests.
Does someone have some hint on how I could achieve this (using xmlrunner)?

In addition, here is what I try to achieve:
I define my tests in a set of classes in the following **myunittest.py** file:

```
import unittest
class TestOne(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, options=None):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self)
        self.__options = options
    def A(self):
        print self.__options.configXML # try to print the parameter
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

and call it from the **main.py** which looks like:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import unittest
import xmlrunner
from uitest import *

def runit(opt):
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestOne(options=opt))
    testrunner = xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='tests', descriptions=True)
    unittest.main(testRunner=testrunner).run(suite)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--configXML", dest="configXML",  help="xml file")
    options = parser.parse_args()
    runit(opt=options)
```

Many thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1):

after several hours trying to figure it out, I came to this solution, which makes my day. I post it here, in case someone comes to the same issue.
The main drawback is that it seems I need to have everything in the same python file. and I run it like:

```
python test.py  --xmlConfig=configFile.xml --xmlRunner
```

with test.py:

```
import unittest
import sys
from optparse import OptionParser
import xmlrunner

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFirstThing(self):
        xmlConfig=options.xmlConfig
        self.assertEqual(xmlConfig,"configFile.xml")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--xmlRunner", "--xmlRunner",  help="perform a unittest and generate XML", dest="xmlRunner", default=False, action='store_true')
    parser.add_option("--xmlConfig", "--xmlConfig", type="string", help="configuration file", dest="xmlConfig", default="config.xml")

    options, arguments = parser.parse_args()
    if options.xmlRunner:
        del sys.argv[1:]
        unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='./xml'))
```